# get all data from special month of each years in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to get data from mysql with special month of each years.
I must use Gregorian calendar for my project. I must tell you an example:
In Gregorian date, date between 2016-12-19 and 2017-01-21 is one month in Gregorian date.
now with the explanation, I want to get data from special month of each years. for example i want to get data from 2011-12-19 and 2012-01-21 to 2016-12-19 and 2017-01-21. I wrote these queries but i haven't got correct results.

first query:

```
select from_unixtime('start_shift', '%Y-%m-%d') from shift where (from_unixtime('start_shift', '%m-%d') between 12-19 and 01-21) and from_unixtime('start_shift', '%Y') > 2010
```

second query:

```
select from_unixtime('start_shift', '%Y-%m-%d') from shift where (from_unixtime('start_shift', '%m-%d') >= 12-19 and (from_unixtime('start_shift', '%m-%d') <= 01-21) and from_unixtime('start_shift', '%Y') > 2010
```

=====================only third query returns correct result==================

third_query:

```
select from_unixtime('start_shift', '%Y-%m-%d') from shift where (from_unixtime('start_shift', '%Y-%m-%d') >= 2016-12-19 and (from_unixtime('start_shift', '%m-%d') <= 2017-01-21)
```

only third query return correct result, but i must use %Y that return year, I don't want to use %Y because if i want to use it,  i must create a large query and this isn't very logic.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: I imagine most people here are fairly familiar with the Gregorian calendar. I suspect your question relates to the Persian calendar. As such, you would normally handle the conversion outside of MySQL. I imagine that this topic is well covered elsewhere

Comment: Hi Dear Strawberry. the question relates to the Persian calendar